# jQuery filter function causing unresponsive script

Tags: jquery, loops, indexof, each

I have a website that is listing a category of products.

Using jQuery, I am looking at each product's title link and filtering out anything with the words "sale", "clearance", or "new".

Then, based on the results I receive, I'm adding a "sale", "clearance", or "new" banner image over the products thumbnail image.

This appears to be working great when my script only finds 1 or 2 products with those words in their title link, but if I try to run my script on a page with, let's say 20 products, my browser freezes and I get an unresponsive script warning.

Would anyone out there mind taking a look at my code below to see where I am causing this issue? From what I can tell, it appears as though I am trying to overlay the "banner" image multiple times per result, which I believe is what's causing my script to become unresponsive.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
// Set CSS position to relative for each thumbnail container
$('.ProductImage').css('position','relative');
// Find the title for each product on the page
var $title = $('div.product a.title');

// START SALE PRODUCTS
var theSaleTitle = $($title);
// Search for all SALE products by finding the word "sale" in the title element
var iSale = $(theSaleTitle).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf('sale') != -1;
});
$(iSale).each(function(){
    // Select each matching title element's parent
    var parentSale = $(iSale).parent();
    // Select the thumbnail image for each parent
    var Sale = $('a img', parentSale);
    // Insert "SALE" ribbon before each thumbnail for products with "sale" in the title element
    $(Sale).each(function() {;
        $('a img', parentSale).before("<img style='position:absolute;top:-3px;left:-3px;border:0;' src='/content/images/sale-ribbon.png'/>");
    });
    // Remove the word "Sale" from the product title for each sale product
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/sale/ig,''))
});
// END SALE PRODUCTS
```

And here is my sample HTML code:

```
<div class="product">
    <a href="#"></a><div data-product="4318" class="ProductImage QuickView" style="position: relative;"><a href="#">
    </a><a href="/sigep-black-mega-flag-tee/"><img alt="SigEp Black Mega Flag Tee" src="/products/4318/images/2369/052183__14662.1363380086.230.230.jpg"></a>
    <div class="QuickViewBtn" style="background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(220, 219, 219)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: none; margin: 0px; top: 96.5px; left: 60px;" data-product="4318">Quick View</div>
</div>

<a class="title " href="/sigep-black-mega-flag-tee/">sale SigEp Black Mega Flag Tee</a>
<span class="price">$19.95</span>

</div>
```

Please let me know if I can provide any further information to help troubleshoot and thanks for taking a look!

UPDATE: As asked, I have shortened my code to smaller example of 1 product and a search for just the word "sale" in the product title link.

Comment: Do you think you could make a reduced case of this code, making it considerably smaller, Emphasizing the part that is giving you performance issues?

Comment: I just edited my original post so that the code examples are much smaller. Let me know if you have enough information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why are you using selectors like that. There might be a performance issue with the way you write your jQuery code. Why not try something like that:

```
// Set CSS position to relative for each thumbnail container
$('.ProductImage').css('position','relative');

// Search for all SALE products by finding the word "sale" in the title element
$('div.product a.title').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('sale') != -1) {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            // Select the thumbnail image for each parent
            .find('a img')
            // Insert "SALE" ribbon before each thumbnail for products with "sale" in the title element
            .before("<img style='position:absolute;top:-3px;left:-3px;border:0;' src='/content/images/sale-ribbon.png'/>");
        // Remove the word "Sale" from the product title for each sale product
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/sale/ig,''))
    }
});
// END SALE PRODUCTS
```

You don't need to iterate over the elements twice. The first time for the filtering and the second time for applying the change.

You don't need so many variables and strange selectors. Use chaining and learn when you can apply an action to multiple elements with one jQuery function.

Comment: Also you could use `.text()` in the end to replace the "sale" string if you need it replaced only in the text content of the anchor element.

Comment: Thanks @Haralan-Dobrev, if I then wanted to look for additional products with the word "clearance" in the title, would I then just add an additional `if` statement and change "sale" to "clearance"?

Comment: You could do that. I would recommend putting the manipulation code in a separate function and to call it when you find a matching word with different arguments.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I'm working on getting to know jQuery better, and it seems like I keep trying to make things more difficult than they have to be :) I'll just have to remember to keep things simple.